# Customize Total row Label when the column uses Measure with HASONEValue Function

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization

the column in the Table Visual is created using following DAX

DAx1 =
Var A = IF(HASONEVALUE(Table[Col1]),[Measure1],[Measure2])
Return
IF(A=[Measure2],A,"Total")

Current O/P: This returns "A" in the total row as well as the col. uses above dax when there is just one row as per col1 in the table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTxKy.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmlqE.png)

Expected O/P: i want the total row to show text "Total" irrespective of the the table has one row or more than one
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vifyR.png)

Note: the text "Total" should be available in the Total row of the table under the column in which above DAX is used .

I tried putting blank condition using another col. in the table:

DAX2 = IF(ISBLANK([Measure3]),"total",[Measure2])

this does'nt gave desired o/p